# Outlook HTTP mail protocol?

Tags: web-services, http, email, outlook, network-protocols

MS Outlook supports HTTP as one of the e-mail access protocols. As a provider, it supports Hotmail, MSN and "Other". Question - where can I find the description of the protocol so that I may implement a custom HTTP mail service for Outlook to consume? Better yet, are there stock implementation out there?

Comment: Have you tried pointing it a something like http://requestb.in/?  One sec, now I'm curious :)

Comment: I completely remember that feature but I can't find it in Outlook 2010